# How to make sure PL/SQL result in classic report is loaded each time page is loaded

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2

I am building personal knowledge base app in APEX 18.2 and having weird issue where report's query is incorrect/not displaying correctly when navigation menu entries are used to pass on item values.

I have one table as a source:

```
HELP_GUIDE(
HELP_GUIDE_ID   NUMBER PRIMARY KEY
APPLICATION_ID  NUMBER
PAGE_ID NUMBER
TITLE   VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)
SUBTITLE    VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)
REGION  VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)
SECTION VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)
HELP_TEXT   CLOB
)
```

I am using PL/SQL function bellow to show HELP_TEXT column in classic report. That column is containing text+images which are created using APEX rich text editor.

```
return q'~

select "HELP_GUIDE_ID", 
"APPLICATION_ID",
"PAGE_ID",
"TITLE",
"SUBTITLE",
"REGION",
"SECTION",
"HELP_TEXT" 


from "#OWNER#"."HELP_GUIDE" 
where "APPLICATION_ID"=:P3_APPLICATION_ID 
and (TITLE=:P3_TITLE OR :P3_TITLE IS NULL)
and (SUBTITLE=:P3_SUBTITLE OR :P3_SUBTITLE IS NULL)
and (REGION=:P3_REGION OR :P3_REGION IS NULL)
and (SECTION=:P3_SECTION OR :P3_SECTION IS NULL)
~';
```

I've used navigation menu entries to set item values(APPLICATION_ID,TITLE etc.) so I can filter what is shown on page. However I don't see consistent behavior.It seems that at once one of the navigation entries is used (child), APEX will continue showing same result. You can see behavior in [video of issue](https://vimeo.com/user98772240/review/337461840/c8d6f35884)

I have tried adding DA to refresh page post submit, process to refresh, creating new page (copied the previous page) then used it as link for navigation, clear cache has been set for each linking yet getting the same result.

Any assistance is more than welcome.

EDIT:

During the further testing issue was resolved. Adding clearer description and resolution:

Navigation entries with "set these items values" set were supposed to act as filter which would pass P3 items (form page items) values which would then in turn be used by SQL expression.

What was missing is to clear cache for page 3 (form page) each time navigation was called, so simply adding page 3 in clear cache section of navigation entry settings resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There's no video behind that link.

Anyway: it seems that - as a source of that classic report - you are using a function body which returns a query. Why? It is usually used when there's something complex, *dynamic*. Query you wrote is just a simple, plain query. If I were you, I'd try with something as simple as

```
SELECT help_guide_id,
       application_id,
       page_id,
       title,
       subtitle,
       region,
       section,
       help_text
  FROM help_guide
 WHERE     application_id = :P3_APPLICATION_ID
       AND (   title = :P3_TITLE
            OR :P3_TITLE IS NULL)
       AND (   subtitle = :P3_SUBTITLE
            OR :P3_SUBTITLE IS NULL)
       AND (   region = :P3_REGION
            OR :P3_REGION IS NULL)
       AND (   section = :P3_SECTION
            OR :P3_SECTION IS NULL)
```

Get rid of double quotes, no need to use them if column names are created without them (apparently, they are) so their names are in uppercase by default, and you can reference any way you want.

As `P3_...` items are page 3 items (I mean, they are all contained on the same page as the report), in order to refresh query result you can:

- set their **Submit when enter pressed** property to YES (or similar, e.g. if they are select lists, you'd set **Page action on selection** to SUBMIT), so - every time you change their value, the report will be refreshed
- when there are many parameters involved (such as in your case), and if query takes some time to execute, the above principle is not the best option. In that case, don't SUBMIT when items are changed, but create a **button** which will just SUBMIT the page (once you enter all parameters you want) and cause report to refresh.

Basically, quite a simple task *from my point of view*. Perhaps I'm not seeing the obvious, but - that's what I think.

Comment: Littlefoot, thanks for the input. Not sure what's with the link of video, it's working fine for me. I believe I was a bit unclear. I am using navigation menu to set item value for P3 then calling that P3 parameter in query. (probably not the smartest thing) Idea is that when you click on one of the navigation menu links, it shows you classic report which in turn has help guide articles related to that subject (they are filtered using above query and navigation list entries).

Comment: As for the quotes and using PL/SQL it is leftover of me trying to use interactive report to show clob which I scraped. I've changed it now as per your suggestion (used SQL query without quotes) and still seeing same behavior.

Comment: You're welcome. Vimeo: no idea, says "Sorry, we couldn’t find that page". Thank you for the explanation; I *think* I understand what you are saying - as if code that is responsible for setting `P3_` items doesn't work properly every time. If that's so, huh - I'm fighting the same *ghost* as well. Shortly: I'm changing environment settings according to what user selects on Page 1. Usually it works OK, sometimes it does not (and keeps the "old" environment). Click here, click there, refresh page, and it works OK again. The worst thing is that it is inconsistent, I can't find a reason.

Comment: If that's what bothers you as well, I'm afraid I don't have the answer, sorry.

Comment: Yes, it seems that it is the same issue. I've noticed that in my case reloading the page does not help but if I load form page then go back to report, it "fixes" itself.

Comment: While trying to replicate issue on other workspace I did manage to resolve the issue. Problem was that P3 items were not cleared afterwards so if I had app id and title in one navigation set and only title on second navigation as P3 items from page 3 were called once I click on first page and continue to second navigation, title would get pulled as well. Issue was resolved by adding clear cache for page 3 (form page for P3 items) in navigation entry settings.

Comment: Clear cache, you say? Thank you for letting us know. I'll have a look at my page and see whether it'll help in my case as well. i'm glad you solved the problem!